# Is there a way to pause a specific executing time slice for a dataset?

Tags: azure-data-factory

wondering if we can pause a slice in execution? I know we can pause a pipeline but then all the executing slices for that pipeline will be paused. Is there a way (UI or programmatic) to pause only a specific slice for a given pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to pause a specific slice currently through UI. You can trying doing so programmatically though through ADF powershell command-lets listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn820234.aspx .

Thanks, Harish

Answer (score 0):

You can PAUSE pipeline using Manage and Monitor App in Azure Data Factory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-monitor-manage-app

Comment: the question is about a slice, not a pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `powershell` to change the status of the Slice.

The Resource Manager `command` has to be like this:

```
set-AzureRMDataFactorySliceStatus -StartDateTime 2017-08-19T00:00:00Z -EndDateTime 2017-08-20T00:00:00Z -DataFactoryName ***DataFactoryName*** -ResourceGroupName ***ResourceGroupName*** -DatasetName "***DatasetName***" -Status "Ready"
```